# Что такое global.lacksGlobal?

Tags: javascript

В [таблице поддержки новых js-фич](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/esnext/) обнаружил такой тест:

> "global" global property is global object

```
var actualGlobal = Function('return this')();
actualGlobal.__system_global_test__ = 42;
return typeof global === 'object' && global && global === actualGlobal && !global.lacksGlobal && global.__system_global_test__ === 42;
```

Что здесь происходит:

1. Получаем глобальный объект как this в вызове функции вне строгого режима
2. Создаём в нём глобальное свойство `__system_global_test__`
3. Проверяем, что у нас вообще есть `global`
4. И он не ложный
5. И он совпадает с настоящим глобальным скоупом
6. и `!global.lacksGlobal`
7. и он содержит то свойство, которое мы создали с правильным значением

**Вопрос: что делает проверка `!global.lacksGlobal`?**

Ещё интересно, есть ли возможность, что `global` есть, но ложный (видимо, `null` три такой проверке) - вроде тоже странная ситуация, но не лишена смысла.

Comment: Это на случай того, что текущий глобал это [полифил, который он сам добавил](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/blob/c8aa02243822a503c184497e1152bb1ae74dfe2a/esnext/compiler-skeleton.html#L12)

Comment: @Grundy, ответы - в ответы?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная проверка добавлена на случай того, чтобы не спутать настоящий `global`, с [полифилом](https://github.com/kangax/compat-table/blob/c8aa02243822a503c184497e1152bb1ae74dfe2a/esnext/compiler-skeleton.html#L12), который добавляется непосредственно на страницу проверки

```
if (typeof global === "undefined") {
  this.lacksGlobal = true;
  window.global = this;
}
```